# About Staying back for Masters before joining a PhD offer in Hand

Tags: phd, masters

I will finish my Bachelor's degree (International) this year and I have received an offer from a top ~15 (US News subject) place in my field for a PhD. While I know I want to work in that field and do a PhD, I don't know my exact area of interest. The university has a good number of good people working in the field so that gives the department some breadth. But I have not studied many of those areas before in detail, and what I have explored is not done there (except perhaps by a newly joined faculty). Is it advisable for me to join the program? Or stay back in my country for 2 years master's, hoping to get a better or more relevant place, and knowing my interests even better?

Secondly The overall ranking of the university is ~30 in US news. Would that affect later prospects in academia and does that qualify as a valid reason to wait for a master's degree?

Edit: I ended up declining the offer and joining an one-year master's program in the EU and developed my interests in the meantime. I have received more relevant offers in this cycle. (But the ranking was not a factor and I made the decision based on interests alone).

Answer (score 0):

Most US PhD programs, at least in STEM, are 5+ years long, accept students directly out of bachelor's, and compared to many other countries consist of a first approximately 2 years of courses with material similar to a masters, with a further 3+ years dedicated to research and writing a thesis.

Which is to say that there is little advantage to deferring a start. In fact, there may be a disadvantage in that you will be delaying your exposure to the actual fields of interest of your PhD Department.

> Secondly The overall ranking of the university is ~30 in US news. Would that affect later prospects in academia and does that qualify as a valid reason to wait for a master's degree?

Rankings aren't really very helpful for understanding your academic career prospects. The quality of your PhD advisor, the resources the Department has for graduate students (salary, travel funds, amount of teaching, is your summer salary covered without teaching?), and your personal capacity to put the time in are much more important. Check these details, but a "top 30" ranked school is likely extremely competitive on these factors.